# I'm getting error. I want to object counting

Tags: opencv, tensorflow, detection, counting

I am using object detection. I want counting object same time. But I am getting error. Could you help please?

Error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\tensorflow2\models\research\object_detection\Object_detection_image_say3.py", line 138, 
    in 
    <module>
    v2.putText(input_frame, counting_mode, (10, 35), font, 0.8, 
    (0,255,255),2,cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX)
    SystemError: <built-in function putText> returned NULL without setting an error
```

Main Code:
I using code the following. I'm getting error.

```
    input_frame = cv2.imread(PATH_TO_IMAGE)
    image_expanded = np.expand_dims(input_frame, axis=0)

    (boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run(
    [detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections],
    feed_dict={image_tensor: image_expanded})

    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

    counting_mode = vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
    input_frame,
    np.squeeze(boxes),
    np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
    np.squeeze(scores),
    category_index,
    use_normalized_coordinates=True,
    line_thickness=2,
    min_score_thresh=0.80)

    if(len(counting_mode) == 0):
    cv2.putText(input_frame, "...", (10, 35), font, 0.8, (0,255,255),2,cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX)                       
    else:
    cv2.putText(input_frame, counting_mode, (10, 35), font, 0.8, 
    (0,255,255),2,cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX) 
    cv2.imshow('tensorflow_object counting_api',input_frame)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: [`visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array`](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/utils/visualization_utils.py#L724) returns a NumPy array, not a string, which [`putText`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga5126f47f883d730f633d74f07456c576) actually expects as second input. What do YOU expect to be written in that line?

Comment: a function is running.

Comment: Creating a display string (and color) for every box location, group any boxes

Comment: Drawing all boxes onto image

Comment: I do these things.

Answer (score 0):

your 2nd cv2putText takes counting_mode as an input
counting_mode is not a string, hence it cannot be display

convert your counting_mode object to a string (str) before injecting it to the cv2.putText

Comment: Hi
" if(len(counting_mode) == 0): "
is not it enough?

Comment: Hi
I do it. But same result.